# Showing Cosh(I x) and Sinh (I x) rather than cosx and sinx?

Tags: complex, expression-manipulation, trigonometry

The following code gives a function expressed in terms of sines and cosines. How to get the analogous with sinh and cosh, coming from the identities: sinx=sinh(Ix)/I and cosx=cosh(Ix)?

```
FullSimplify[ DSolve[{y'''[z] == -I*Betta*y'[z] + B}, y[z], z] /. 
Solve[0 == 
 C[3] + C[2]*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  C[1]/I*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(2*I*Betta) && 
0 == C[3] + C[2]*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] - 
  C[1]/I*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] - B/(2*I*Betta) && 
1 == C[2]*I*(I*Betta)^0.5*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  C[1]*(I*Betta)^0.5*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(I*Betta) && 
1 == -C[2]*I*(I*Betta)^0.5*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  C[1]*(I*Betta)^0.5*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(I*Betta), {C[1],
 C[2], C[3], B}] ]// TraditionalForm
```

Comment: Hmm, `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False]` fails to prevent it. -- A side issue, you might find it easier to deal symbolically with the exponent `1/2` (treated as exact) instead of `0.5` (treated as approximate). See, for starters, [Exact and Approximate Results](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html).

Comment: @MichaelE2 when you say it fails to prevent it, do you mean it didnt work? In fact, I tried it and still I'm getting sines and cosines

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I meant it fails to prevent `Cosh[I *...]` from becoming `Cos[...]` automatically, the same as what you observed.  Apparently, the option prevents only some trig simplifications. If it's only output formatting you're after, `Inactivate[FullSimplify[ ...], Sinh | Cosh] // TraditionalForm` will work. You would have to `Activate[]` it, to compute with it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks. Now it works, but I still may need to have a different output (the one that I get is still different from the one that I have as a reference). I was wondering if there is a way to investigate (see) all the different alternative forms of output, pretty as much as we could see on Wolfram Alpha. By the way I was trying the Inactivate function over DSolve, to have the solution of the ODE as a function of sinh and cosh only, but it doesnt work

Comment: @AndreaG show us the reference solution.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal This is the output form I am looking for.
  `k = (Sinh[(1 - I) Sqrt[Betta/2] z] - 
     2 z Sinh[(1 - I)/2*Sqrt[Betta/2]])/((1 - I)*
      Sqrt[Betta/2] Cosh[(1 - I)/2 Sqrt[Betta/2]] - 
     2 Sinh[(1 - I)/2 Sqrt[Betta/2]]);`
 It is correct, made by hand, after many substitutions using Eulers formulas and other relationship between sin,sinh,cos,cosh. C1,C2,C3 and B should come directly from the solution of the system. however, I have to report that the way Mathematica defines the constants after DSolve is different from how I defined them by hand.